# How to label plots in a merged image

Tags: r

I had plotted 8 graphs and in order to see them together I merged them into a single image with 4 rows and 2 columns, but I am not able to label them as a), b), c), d), e), f), g) and h). Please provide me with a solution for this. Thanks in advance[image]

I have used the following code:

```
library(magick)
    
# List of your input TIFF files (replace these with your file paths)
file_list <- c("D:/Graphs/NL.tiff", "D:/Graphs/LA.tiff", "D:/Graphs/LFW.tiff", "D:/Graphs/LDW.tiff",
                   "D:/Graphs/SL.tiff", "D:/Graphs/SG.tiff", "D:/Graphs/NB.tiff", "D:/Graphs/SFW.tiff")
    
# Create an output file name (e.g., merged_graphs.tiff)
output_file <- "merged_graphs6.tiff"
   
# Function to merge the images into a 4x2 grid
merge_and_save <- function(files, output_file) {
  images <- image_read(files)
  n_images <- length(images)
    
  if (n_images != 8) {
    stop("You must provide exactly 8 input images for a 4x2 layout.")
  }
      
  # Create two rows, each with 4 graphs
  top_row <- image_append(images[1:4], stack = TRUE)
  bottom_row <- image_append(images[5:8], stack = TRUE)
      
  # Combine the two rows side by side
  combined_image <- image_append(c(top_row, bottom_row), stack = FALSE)
      
  # Save the merged image as a TIFF file
  image_write(combined_image, path = output_file, format = "tiff")
}
    
# Call the function to merge the images and save as a TIFF file
merge_and_save(file_list, output_file)
```

Comment: Can you also add a minimal reproducible example of your code. This helps everyone to understand, what packages you used to generate these plots.

Comment: @MarcelloZago i updated the question with code i had used, please do help me

Comment: If that is base graphics, then for each of your plots you can use `title(...)`. If that is ggplot2, I think it's better to go with a single plot and `facet_*`, which will give per-facet labels ("strips").

Comment: Since you're combining image files, then the labels you create would more easily be done at graph creation (I'm assuming they were created in R, ergo my previous comment about base-v-ggplot2.)

Comment: @r2evans i have 52 more such graphs to combine, so

Comment: @r2evans i used ggplot in r to get this but how to use facet, can you please provide cde for that

Comment: I feel this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Rather than trying to label plots you have already produced, it would be better to modify your workflow to produce a single graphic with the labels included.  @r2evans has already made eminently sensible suggestions about how this could be done.

Comment: I'm not going to *guess* at how you created these plots. Share sample data (perhaps just two groups, pls post the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is the sample data) and the code to make them.

Comment: @ORBITTINGARYABHATA, I suggest you open a new question. r2evans is correct it is (usually) much easier to create graphs joined in an image using the ggplot2 inbuilt `facet()` functions. It even labels the graph for you. But explaining how to use `facet_wrap()` for your specific problem will require looking at how one of these graphs is generated in the first place. I think a good way to start is by asking how to create multiple graphs from a sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a perfect demonstration, but I'll use `mtcars` to show one way to convert monolithic plots of each group into a faceted image instead.

I'll assume that there is one dataset that you subset for each of your eight plots. To mimic that, I'll produce three plots with each of `mtcars$cyl` (4, 6, and 8).

```r
library(ggplot2)
gg4 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl == 4), aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point()
gg6 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl == 6), aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point()
gg8 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl == 8), aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

The first is:

[image: scatter plot, mtcars cyl 4]

We can add labels to each of these in many ways, though I think the easiest is to add a title to each.

```r
gg4 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl == 4), aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "mtcars, with 4 cylinders")
# same for gg6 and gg8
```

[image: same image with a title/label]

Now, if you repeat this for each of your eight images, you can combine them using `magick` as you were intending to do.

---

However, it might be easier if you do a single plot, using facets. One of the (huge!) benefits of using facets is that whatever code you're using to create the bars and error-bars in your current plot will likely need no modification, just use the whole data instead of subset frames, and add the call to `facet_wrap` (or `facet_grid`, but I'm using wrap here).

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(cyl ~ .)
```

[image: ggplot of mtcars, faceted by cyl]

Some ways this can be adjusted:

- with `facet_wrap`, you can add `nrow=4, ncol=2` to get the 4x2 arrangement you showed;
- the labels here are pretty boring, you can add a column to `mtcars` that is a little more descriptive, such as

  ```r
  transform(mtcars, cyl = paste("These cars have", cyl, "cylinders")) |>
    ggplot(aes(disp, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(cyl ~ .)
  ```

  [image: ggplot, mtcars, facet on cyl, more descriptive labels]

  (I used `base::transform`, though just for convenience. Other base-R column assignment works, as would `dplyr` or other R dialects.)
- the labels ("strips" in ggplot parlance) can be themed a bit, though perhaps not *exactly* like the titles far above in this answer; see [`?theme`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html), specifically looking at parameters named `strip.*`.

---

Last point: if you did eight plots based on eight different `data.frame`s, then we can still so a single plot after combining the eight frames into one. In that case, we have a few options:

**Base R**: for this, all frames must have the same columns with the same names and classes, though they can be in different orders:

```r
combined <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8)
```

If there are columns missing in any of them, you will need to add them manually. (There are many ways to do this, lmk if you need to go down this route.)

**`dplyr::bind_rows`** is a bit simpler in that it does not require all the same, though obviously the columns used for plotting must be present in all. This version allows columns in one frame to not exist in another, and it will automatically fill the missing column values with `NA` for a group.

```r
combined <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8)
```

One thing that this (and `rbindlist`, below) offers is the ability to add an "id" field, indicating from which frame each row was copied. That is, if the eight frames are relatively identical but you don't "know" that `df1` (for instance) is from London just by looking at it, then if we use `bind_rows(..., .id="id")`, then `combined$id` will be an integer column with a `1` for all rows copied from `df1`, `2` for all rows copied from `df2`, etc. We can make that even a little better if we have a named list of frames, we get a `character` column instead of just integers. As a demonstration of this using some subset frames:

```r
mt4 <- subset(mtcars, cyl == 4)[1:3,]
mt6 <- subset(mtcars, cyl == 6)[1:3,]
dplyr::bind_rows(mt4, mt6, .id = "id")
#                id  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710      1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D       1 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230        1 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Mazda RX4       2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag   2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Hornet 4 Drive  2 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
dplyr::bind_rows("Four cylinders" = mt4, "Six cylinders" = mt6, .id = "id")
#                            id  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710     Four cylinders 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D      Four cylinders 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230       Four cylinders 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Mazda RX4       Six cylinders 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag   Six cylinders 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Hornet 4 Drive  Six cylinders 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

Similarly, `data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df2, ...), idcol="id", fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)` works in the same ways, with the need for two more arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and could finally succeeded in adding the labels, here i provide the code for people who are interested to do similar things

```
library(magick)

# List of your input TIFF files (replace these with your file paths)
file_list <- c("Path1", "Path2",.....)

# Create an output file name (e.g., merged_graphs.tiff)
output_file <- "merged_graphs_with_labels.tiff"

# Function to merge the images into a 4x2 grid and add labels with custom size and positions
merge_and_save <- function(files, output_file) {
  images <- image_read(files)
  n_images <- length(images)
  
  if (n_images != 8) {
    stop("You must provide exactly 8 input images for a 4x2 layout.")
  }
  
  # Create two rows, each with 4 graphs
  top_row <- image_append(images[1:4], stack = TRUE)
  bottom_row <- image_append(images[5:8], stack = TRUE)
  
  # Combine the two rows side by side
  combined_image <- image_append(c(top_row, bottom_row), stack = FALSE)
  
  # Add labels to the graphs with custom size and positions
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "a)", location = "+30+20", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "b)", location = "+3669+20", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "c)", location = "+30+2110", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "d)", location = "+3669+2110", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "e)", location = "+30+4210", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "f)", location = "+3669+4210", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "g)", location = "+30+6310", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
  combined_image <- image_annotate(combined_image, "h)", location = "+3669+6310", size = 75, color = "black", font = "Arial-Bold", weight = 600)
```